# Why this code doesn't write any data to output file to create movie using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, avi

I am trying to create some video from a set of large raw images that I have.

The code is as follow:

```
int imageWidth=687;
int imageHeight=916;
int fps=3;
int ex=-1;
CvSize size = cvSize(imageWidth,imageHeight);
VideoWriter outputVideo; 
outputVideo.open(MovieOutput, ex, fps, size, true);
if(outputVideo.isOpened())
{
    cout << "error opening output video";
}
for(int frameNo=0;frameNo<58;frameNo++)
{
    ostringstream outfilename;
    outfilename << InputDir<< (frameNo+1)<<".jpg";
    rawimages.Read(frameNo);
    Mat image=rawimages.ToOpencvImage();
    imwrite( outfilename.str(), image );
    outputVideo <<image;
    imshow("Image", image);
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
```

I can see that images are shown on screen and also different jpg are saved on hard disk.

I can see that the output avi is created, but its size is zero.

What is the problem with this code?

some note:

The output size is very big. Can it generate movie with that size?

Comment: This condition looks like it should be negated: `if(outputVideo.isOpened())`

Comment: @hmjd You are right. It is working now, but I can not play it! When try to play it, media player (on windows says media player encounter problem playing the movie)

Comment: Do you get a codec selection dialogue on execution? If not, try passing "CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'B', ' ')" or "CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')" instead of ex.

Comment: @FvD you are right. After selecting some codec, I found one that works.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments: you pass the second parameter to the VideoWriter open command with a value of -1. This is supposed to open a codec selection dialogue in Windows, but as of OpenCV 2.4.5, the dialogue seems to be bugged - it appears, but I couldn't manage to write to a file afterwards.

Selecting a codec directly works fine and makes more sense in my opinion. More info about this command and available codecs can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?videowriter-open).

```
outputVideo.open("example.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), fps, size, true);
```